# Showing images on a page with document.write()

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to post an image when in my javascript file with document.write(). The problem is that when I try it, the image always comes up broken. Here is the code. Am I writing the tag wrong? I've tested the images on non-javascript pages and they seem to show up fine.

```
var replay = "yes";
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
userChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        document.write("The result is a tie!");
    }
    if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            document.write('<img src="images\orna.jpg\">');
        } else {
            document.write("Computer chose paper. Computer wins.");
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            document.write("Computer chose scissors. Computer wins.");
        } else {
            document.write("Computer chose rock. Player wins.");
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            document.write("Computer chose paper. Player wins.");
        } else {
            document.write("Computer chose scissors. Computer wins.");
        }
    }
};
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Comment: What would a full URL to some of your images be? example.com/??? <- what should the ??? be?

Comment: The image is in a folder on my flash drive. My html file is one level above it. So an example would be images\rock.jpg

Comment: document.write("<img src='images/rock.jpg' />");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it, I think you just have to replace backslashes with slashes: `'<img src="images/orna.jpg">'`. Here is a demo (click "run" until win):

```js
var replay = "yes";
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
userChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
}
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    document.write("The result is a tie!");
  }
  if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      document.write('<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLr3o.jpg?s=128&g=1">');
    } else {
      document.write("Computer chose paper. Computer wins.");
    }
  }
  if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      document.write("Computer chose scissors. Computer wins.");
    } else {
      document.write("Computer chose rock. Player wins.");
    }
  }
  if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "paper") {
      document.write("Computer chose paper. Player wins.");
    } else {
      document.write("Computer chose scissors. Computer wins.");
    }
  }
};
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Comment: How would I go about using a variable to enter the image path? For example for the tie breaker, I would need to use the variables in order to see which image to put out for the tie. Would it be something like `'<img src="images/" +choice+ ".jpg">'`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write()`. It is harmful. Instead, what you need to do is create a `<div></div>` and append stuff to that.

Anyway, the reason your things aren't working you have unescaped `\`s. For example, if you have `<img src="images\orna.jpg\">`, the `\`s are acting as escape characters, and are ignored. Your string '' evaluates to `'<img src="imagesorna.jpg">'`, which is definitely not what you want. Make sure the file paths are correct, and if they are, you need to change them to

```
'<img src="images\\orna.jpg\\">'
```

At any rate, create a `div`, and then using jQuery or pure Javascript, append elements to them. You can do that by accessing its `innerHTML`, or by using the `.append()` jQuery method

Answer (score 0):

I agree with scrblndr3 that document.write is bad. Do some reading on it.

To help you understand what's wrong, here's a bit of explanation.

First, "\" is a Windows specific file path segment delimiter. Browsers and anything unix based use "/" to delimit segments of a path. Secondly, in your path string, you escape the final double quote, as your string is wrapped with single quotes, this is unnecessary and breaking. The correct command would be:

```
document.write('<img src="images/orna.jpg">');
```

or if your string was double quoted, you would have to escape the internal double quotes like:

```
document.write("<img src=\"images/orna.jpg\">");
```