# Syntax Error, Illegal return statement

Tags: javascript

Hi I have this code right now

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
};

if (choice1 === "Rock")
{
    if (choice2 === "Scissors")
    {
        return "Rock wins!";
    }
    else (choice2 = "Paper")
    {
        return "Paper wins!";
    }
}
```

but I keep getting a Synatax error, illegal return statement.

I don't understand why I am getting this error, am I doing something wrong?  I believe the syntax is all correct.

I am using an online editor by the way, not an actual IDE.

Comment: `choice2 = "Paper"` looks like a typo

Comment: Maybe you wanted `else if(choice2 == "Paper")`? - and wrap the if inside the `compare` function :)

Comment: Go cheat on your classmate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/20622970/1636522 :D

Comment: Thanks LightStyle, that did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to write the following

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }

    if (choice1 === "Rock")
    {
        if (choice2 === "Scissors")
        {
            return "Rock wins!";
        }
        else if (choice2 === "Paper")
        {
            return "Paper wins!";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The else statement, written this way, makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

> *return statement is only valid inside the function.*

Look at the code

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
};
```

this part of the code will work fine. but after this semicolon `(;)` a separate part of the code is started which eventually *is not the part of function* as you function ended with the semicolon, that's why lower part of the code is giving this error.

Second thing, Your else statement makes no sense. You code should be like this

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    if (choice1 === "Rock") {
        if (choice2 === "Scissors") {
            return "Rock wins!";
        } else if (choice2 === "Paper") {
            return "Paper wins!";
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I made this mistake, when using `debugger;` or line break somewhere, don't return in your browser's console. This returns the same syntax error because your return is not wrapped in a function.

In console don't:
`return choice1 === choice2` // error

Instead just do:
`choice1 === choice2` // true or false